# How to change color header on jQuery Mobile by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, colors

Does anybody know how to change jQuery Mobile **color header** by using Javascript, I've no idea how to create on javascript but successful create it on CSS.

```
       .ui-page .ui-header{
        background: #FF0000 !important;
        }

on the top .ui-header shown the color but I do not know how to implement on javascript
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".ui-page .ui-header").css("background-color", "#FF0000");
```

Comment: When I use '.ui-page' the whole page turn to red color then I just remove the '.ui-page', and seem all goes perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I got the answer, Thanks to Aweary.

```
$(".ui-header").css("background-color", "#FF0000");
```

Comment: @azimhamdan, the correct thing to do is accept Aweary's answer.  You don't need to create another answer that is no different than the one that helped you.